# how to change the download path/location in protractor

Tags: download, protractor, config

whenever my scripts are downloading something I want to change the download path of the protractor.It usually downloads in defualt downloads folder ie c://downloads.However i want to place it under C:\Automation\test-FrameworkRefactoring_3\lib.This is how my protractor.config.js looks like

```
 capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {

        prefs: {
            download: {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'directory_upgrade': true,
                'default_directory':  'C:\Automation\test-FrameworkRefactoring_3\lib'
            }
        }
    }
},
```

could anyone please suggest anything on this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your working direction is in `test-FrameworkRefactoring_3`. Then

```
const path = require("path");
// the rest your config
"default_directory": path.join(process.cwd(), "lib")
```

That's what I actually used back in times on windows

Comment: am sorry but that didnt work, it opens the pop up asking me save the file an any directory.I Dont want that alert pop up where it asks me to save the file. i want the script to save it under the specific directory without asking for alert pop up

Comment: thats another question

Answer (score 0):

This is currently working for me. I don't remember if you have to create the directory first or not. You'll have to try and see. In any case, I am running thousands of tests daily using this setup and it's working. Protractor v7.0.0

```
prefs: {
  download: {
    prompt_for_download: false,
    default_directory: path.resolve(__dirname, '../downloads/')
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var downloadsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '/abc/xyz'); //download location

 prefs: {
        download: {
          'prompt_for_download': false,
          'default_directory': downloadsPath
        }
      }
```

This worked for me